# Are expressions considered to be statements but not the other way? Confusion

Tags: java, expression

Simple statements are syntactic units carrying out actions. Returning, assinging an expression to a new or already declared variable for example.

A literal is considered an expression, but if an expression contains multiple operands and evaluates them to a single result then we can say an expression carries out an action of computation, returning its resulting value.

In that sense an expression is not a type of statement if it also carries out an action?

Comment: @Sweeper I tagged c#

Comment: @Eran, I replaced C# with Java for you. I am sure I am ok with that too, there may be difference between the 2 but that is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JLS 14.8**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) states the relationship between statements and expressions:

> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following them with semicolons.... An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, the value is discarded.

A **Statement** can be one of the following:

> Statement:
>
> - **StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement**
> - LabeledStatement
> - IfThenStatement
> - IfThenElseStatement
> - WhileStatement
> - ForStatement

A **StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement**, can be one of the following:

> StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
>
> - Block
> - EmptyStatement
> - **ExpressionStatement**
> - AssertStatement
> - SwitchStatement
> - DoStatement
> - BreakStatement
> - ContinueStatement
> - ReturnStatement
> - SynchronizedStatement
> - ThrowStatement
> - TryStatement

An **ExpressionStatement** is:

> ExpressionStatement:
>
> - StatementExpression ;

Where **StatementExpression** is one of the following:

> StatementExpression:
>
> - Assignment
> - PreIncrementExpression
> - PreDecrementExpression
> - PostIncrementExpression
> - PostDecrementExpression
> - MethodInvocation
> - ClassInstanceCreationExpression

To answer your question:

Some (but not all) expressions can be used as statements.

Here are some examples of expressions that can be used as a statement:

```
x = 5;
new StringBuilder ();
someMethodCall ();
```

Here's an example of an expression that cannot be used as a statement (since you must do something with its value):

```
(x > y) ? x : y;
```

Therefore not all expressions can be considered as statements.

And as for the other direction, most statements are not expressions.

Comment: “An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, the value is discarded.” Wait, is it even possible for an expression not to have a value? That sounds impossible, an expression should always evaluate to a value.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer a MethodInvocation expression doesn't necessarily have a value (it can be a `void` method).

Comment: so it is untrue that an expression always evaluates to a value? That is something pretty huge to find out...

Comment: @PatrikNusszer yes, it is untrue.

Comment: Can you say that expressions are a subset of statements?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer no, as I wrote in my answer (and quoted the JLS), not all expressions can be used as statements. For example `(x > y) ? x : y` cannot be used as a statement.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer `5*4;` is not an expression statement, and therefore doesn't pass compilation as is. The other two contain assignment expressions and therefore can be used as statements.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer sorry, I don't have time to chat

Comment: Sorry, that was accidental.

Comment: What is the difference between a return statement containing an expression and an assignment statement containing an expression that makes the assignment to be called an expression statement but not the return?